# Получение токена при авторизации

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Задача состоит в получении токена после ввода логина и пароля в новом окне через window.open по ссылке

```
const LoginPage = ({ setAuth }) => {
  const FrameLogin = () => {
    let childWindow = window.open(
      "ссылка",
      "child",
      "width=500, height=500, id='child, location='true'"
    );

   
  };
```

После ввода логина пароля, в адресной строке появляется токен, но как его получить и на что вообще реагировать? Знаю, что можно взять window.location, но в какой момент?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

https://learn.javascript.ru/window-methods
раздел Доступ к новому окну.

В коде с формой (в новом окне) вставить

```
<script>window.opener.token = window.location.href;window.opener.parseToken();</script>
```

а в родительском распарсить window.token в функции window.parseToken.

Вот пример, который работает, если ввести его в консоли:

```
window.parseToken = function (){
  console.log(window.token);
}

var newWin = window.open("about:blank", "hello", "width=200,height=200");

newWin.document.write("<script>window.opener.token = window.location.href; window.opener.parseToken();</script>");
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Играйтесь. )